# How to set all files under a folder to a specified filetype?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, filetype

I have some zsh function files that I should not add extensions to for the convenience of calling, i.e. `my_func` instead of `my_func.zsh`. But this causes an issue that Neovim cannot detect their filetypes since I also use nvim-treesitter that does `:syntax off`/`:filetype off` by default.

So, is it possible to have a local setting file located in a folder so that those files at the same level will all be set to the specified filetype?

Comment: If there's no good answer,  there's a workaround.  I have a similar problem with `*.py` files that I want to display in a web browser; the server executes them instead.  What I did is create matching `*.code` files for references in the HTML. The trick is to have one of each pair be a symbolic link to the other (hard links are even better, but you have to occasionally check to make sure they haven't become unlinked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, nvim-treesitter does not call `:filetype off` by default.

Secondly, `:filetype on` is enabled by default(`:h nvim-defaults`).

Finally, you can use `vim.filetype.add` (`:h lua-filetype`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about autoload functions or just scripts, putting a zsh shebang or `#compdef` at the beginning should work fine for filetype detection. Otherwise, `# vim: ft=zsh` near the beginning or end (`:help modeline`).